# Comparing order of magnitudes using big O

Tags: number-theory, computational-complexity

For the trial division factorization, for a positive integer $n$, I know that the number of divisions by all primes in the range $1$ to $\sqrt{n}$ is approximately (using prime number theorem) $2\times\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\ln n}=O\left(\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\ln n}\right)$ and the number of divisions by all the integers in the range $1$ to $\sqrt{n}$ is $\sqrt{n}=O(\sqrt{n})$.

I am asked to evaluate these expressions for $n=7^{76}$ and $n=11^{111}$ and then compare their orders of magnitude using the big $O$ notation. What do I have to do for the latter part? I simply do not understand what "compare their orders of magnitude using the big $O$ notation" means?

Comment: Me neither, apart from saying that their ratio is in $O(\ln n)$... Anyway $O$ absorbs the constants, so you can use $\log_7$ and $\log_{11}$ instead of $\ln$ to simplify calculations.